# How do you earn the "A Past Wreathed in Shadows" achievement?

Tags: sunless-sea

The achievement requires you to "complete the game without ever choosing a past." But what does that mean? I just finished a game with the Zeppelin ending, without choosing a past, but didn't earn this achievement. Then I re-loaded and tried retiring to my mansion; that didn't work either. For reference, this is the third captain in my lineage; one went NORTH, and the other found his father's bones. This is the first captain I've played with that didn't have a past.

What endings allow you to earn A Past Wreathed in Shadows? (Do only Ambitions count?) Do I need to start from scratch with a new captain with no lineage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this badge, you need to complete an Ambition. Or, at least, when I finished the Aestival Ambition, I got this badge (and when finishing via Zeppelin or retiring at home, I didn't get the badge). I didn't need to restart a new lineage – I just needed to complete an ambition with a captain that didn't choose a past.

There are two Ambitions you can complete without choosing a past: Aestival, and the TRAVELLER RETURNING. I'm not sure if TRAVELLER will trigger this badge, but since it's a [recognized Ambition](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/Objective:_Ambition), it should.

Comment: I can confirm that Traveller Returning will get this.